# Delete from folder but not from subfolders

Tags: powershell

I want to delete files from a directory with a given extension after a given number of days, but I want to let subfolders untouched, I want to do this with PowerShell.
I mention that I don't know how many subfolders I have.
That is what I've done until now.

```
[string]$Path = Read-Host -Prompt "Path"
[string]$exe = Read-Host -Prompt "Extension"
[int]$Size = Read-Host -Prompt "Dimension"
[int]$Days = Read-Host -Prompt "Days"

Get-ChildItem –Path "$Path" -Recurse -Include *.$exe | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days))} | Where { $_.Length / 1kb -lt $Size } | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: If you don't want to touch subfolders, simply remove `-Recurse`

Comment: I tryed to delete -Recurse, but after that did not delete anything, not even in folder

Comment: And you're sure that you have `*.exe` files directly in `$path` that are both old enough and small enough to satisfy your input criteria?

Comment: Yeah, I am sure

Comment: Change `-Include` to `-Filter` AND remove `-Recurse`

Comment: Daniel, you are a true hero, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the comments in an answer and adding my own 2 cents:

- Remove argument `-Recurse` which causes `Get-ChildItem` to *recurse* into sub folders
- Replace `-Include` by `-Filter`. Not strictly necessary but more efficient, as filters work on the provider level, so PowerShell has less work to do.
- The `Where-Object` calls can be combined into one.
- The variable `$path` as argument doesn't need to be quoted, even if it may contain spaces.
- The date to be compared should be calculated only once before the loop, to make the code clearer. In general, code will be more efficient if we do as little as possible in the inner loop, though in this case it doesn't really matter. The directory iteration and file deletion are comparatively much more expensive.

```
$minDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days)

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter *.$exe | Where-Object {
    ( $_.LastWriteTime -lt $minDate ) -and ( $_.Length / 1kb -lt $Size )
} | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

Note: the parenthesis in the condition are not necessary, because `-and` has less [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence?view=powershell-7.1) than the other operators. I still prefer to use parenthesis for optical grouping of the sub conditions. Makes the code easier to read in my opinion.